# Magento giving strange url when I enable 'Use Secure URLs in Frontend'

Tags: php, magento, ssl, https

When I enable 'Use Secure URLs in Frontend' it messes up the urls of secured pages. For example, this is the url I get for the checkout page

http://www.domain.com/https://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/

It seems as though it's adding an extra 'http://www.domain.com/' before the secure domain. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please provide your template code and what data is stored in your secure config path?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue a few weeks ago. I never got to the bottom of why it occurred but the quick fix is:

Within a MySQL client run the following SQL:

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

This will return a nice string of data. Then run:

```
update core_config_data set value = "https://yourdomain/" where config_id = ?
```

Where ? is the config_id of the ID from the SQL in the select statement. You may need to clear the cache or delete /var from the magento root directory. Yet this should get you back operational. If not let me know and I can help more.